# SonataAdminBundle overwrite date template

Tags: php, sonata-admin, symfony4

I use sonata admin bundle and my question
How o overwtite this template ?

```
vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Resources/views/CRUD/list_date.html.twig

'date' => '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/list_date.html.twig',
```

maybe some approach in config ?

```
sonata_admin:
templates:
   date => '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/list_date.html.twig',
```

but it's not work's.

I tried created `templates/bundles/SonataAdmin/CRUD/list_date.html.twig` but still sonata render data in `vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Resources/views/CRUD/list_date.html.twig`
How to corect create overwrite template ?

I tried create like in cookbook `templates/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/Resources/views/CRUD/list_date.html.twig` and clear cache but still data rendered in old template. I using Symfony 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [standard template override](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html) from Symfony. Means it should work with file: `templates/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/CRUD/list_date.html.twig`.

Comment: hmmm, I tried created `templates/bundles/SonataAdmin/CRUD/list_date.html.twig` but still sonata render data in `vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Resources/views/CRUD/list_date.html.twig`
How to corect create overwrite template ?

Comment: I tried create like in cookbook `templates/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/Resources/views/CRUD/list_date.html.twig` and clear cache but still data rendered in old template. I using Symfony 4

Comment: I understood
this is right path 
`templates/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/CRUD/list_date.html.twig`

Comment: It should be like last comment (fixed in my post missing Bundle keyword)